# Загрузка файлов, нарисованных с помощью html5, на сервер

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript, html5

Есть html5 рисовалка. Теперь есть необходимость загружать творения пользователя на сервер.

Отправляю на сервер через ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/filesave/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'imageBase64': document.getelementbyid("canvas").todataurl("image/png")
    }
});
```

Однако на сервере массив `$_FILES` пуст.

Comment: Переменная, в которой все это добро, называется imageBase64 и она в $_POST - в соответствии с предоставленным кодом.

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ищите в $_POST

зыж только зачем еще раз этот вопрос задавать?